# problem with ngModel and databinding to Date Calendar and dropdown

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use ngModel to databind to the selection made with ngbDatePicker and ngbDropDownMenu. I click on the date and when I clicked Save button, I get an alert message saying [object object]. When I databinded NgModel to the dropdown, it also is not working.

I am using the alert message to test the content of my object which holds the datepicker and dropdown values.

Hello,

To get the ngModel working, I found the answer at this site. I hope it helps others

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples

Comment: can you change the alert message for a console.log, so that you can check on the browser console the value that you are getting from datepicker and dropdown, eg. `console.log('my value is:', this.meetingRequest);`

Comment: to  see more information, you can add the value through string interpolation, go to your html template and add this `{{  meetingRequest | json }}`.